# Component Angular have size (Width Height)

Tags: angular

I have an issue in Angular 4.

I thinks component in angular doesn't have size (width x height) like this:

[image: Angular issue]

So I can't render new component because old component is still there, I can't change value of this.

Comment: take a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940252/angular-component-host-element-width-and-height-are-0?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can set it manually as follow,

Let's say you have a component called  `home.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'home',
  styleUrls: ['home.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
)}
```

So in `home.component.css`, you can set its height and width as below,

```
:host {             // host targets selector: 'home'

    display: block;
    left: 0;

    width: 100%;    // takes parent width        
    OR    
    widht: 1000px   // screen of having 1000px of width


    height: 100%;   // takes parent height    
    OR        
    height: 1000px  // screen of having 1000px of height
}
```

Comment: Sorry sir, please help me one more. If i render component by ngFor. my old component still have old size and my new component have this size too. Because of that my new component cant show in html. Please help me make component don't have size, only element inside have. Many thanks

Comment: @BaoBao. what happened?

Comment: I can't understand your problem completely .

Comment: Hi sir @micronyks. I show my issue in my last answer. Please help me. Many thanks.

Comment: display: block is the key here. It seems that browsers (chrome at least) default to display: inline for elements that aren't known to them.