# Angular component host element width and height are 0

Tags: angular

When I inspect my component element, sometimes its `width` and `height` are 0 even though if I inspect inside, the elements the component include have a certain width and height. This leads me not to able to style the host element because even when I set `width` and `height` to the host element by declaring `:host { // styles }` it doesn't work. So I ended up adding an  extra `div` wrapping around the component element to give some `width` and `height` which I find it verbose. Is it a natural thing? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From what I can see by inspecting a rendered Angular component in the browser, the host element has the attribute `display: inline` by default. As mentioned in a few questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1423294/1009922), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2491068/1009922)), the size of inline elements cannot be changed with CSS styles.

In order for the width and height style attributes to be effective, you should set the `display` attribute of the host element to `block` or `inline-block`:

```
display: block;
display: inline-block;
```

You can see an example in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-wz3p1j), where the following CSS is used:

```
:host {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason that the :host display should be inline? Would it have any unwanted effect if it's changed to block?

Comment: @QianChen - The host element is `inline` by default but that can be changed. The only side effect that I know is on the layout, which is what we want here. You can also choose `inline-block`, to preserve the ability to insert the component in a line.

Comment: Should I add it to every component? Can I add it somewhere to apply it globally